# Socorro com Javascript = ( =

Tags: javascript

Era para a média aparcer 5.4 e ta aparecendo 48.8
(considerando a entrada: 2.0 4.0 7.5 8.0
6.4)

```js
var entrada = require('readline-sync')

var linha = entrada.question().split(' ')
var segundoValor = entrada.question()

var N1 = parseFloat(linha[0]).toFixed(1)
var N2 = parseFloat(linha[1]).toFixed(1)
var N3 = parseFloat(linha[2]).toFixed(1)
var N4 = parseFloat(linha[3]).toFixed(1)

var media = ((N1 * 2) + (N2 * 3) + (N3 * 4) + (N4 * 1) / 10)

if(media >= 7){
    console.log('Media: ', media)
    console.log('Aluno aprovado.')
}
```

Comment: Não seria por causa dos parenteses? Da forma que você está fazendo, `(N4 * 1)` será dividido por 10 antes de ser somado com os outros valores, já que divisão tem prioridade sobre soma. Tente colocar o `/ 10` do lado de fora dos parenteses.

Comment: Você entrou com 5 parâmetros mas está considerando apenas 4. Seria isto? Se não for, para que serve o último parâmetro? O "6.4".

Comment: Tens 5 numeros na entrada mas só usas 4... podes explicar melhor essa parte para poder responder também?

Answer (score 2):

o problema é como o amigo acima disse mesmo:

```js
//var entrada = require('readline-sync')
var entrada = "2.0 4.0 7.5 8.0 6.4"

var linha = entrada.split(' ')
//var segundoValor = entrada.question()

var N1 = parseFloat(linha[0]).toFixed(1)
var N2 = parseFloat(linha[1]).toFixed(1)
var N3 = parseFloat(linha[2]).toFixed(1)
var N4 = parseFloat(linha[3]).toFixed(1)
var N5 = parseFloat(linha[4]).toFixed(1)

var media = ((N1 * 2) + (N2 * 3) + (N3 * 4) + (N4 * 1)) / 10

if(media >= 7){
    console.log('Media: ', media)
    console.log('Aluno aprovado.')
}
console.log('Media: ', media)
```